# How to User "Run" Command in Selinium Ide?

Tags: selenium-ide

[i have been assigned to present about 'run'command in selenium IDE but icant found any related examples or documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSiEI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I make a lot of use of the run command. I use it to make up a test out of building blocks.

So, if I'm testing something that sits behind a login form, then I might have a test which is the happy path for login, and then a series of tests to test the feature. I don't want to have to have the login steps in each test - as if the login functionality changes I'd need to rebuild all of my scripts.

So, in this case, I'd have a test called @login (I use @ to prefix those that are building blocks for easy identification and so that they float to the top of the list of tests in the IDE view) which would do the simplest thing possible to log in successfully.

When writing my tests for the new feature, I'd start with the following

```
Command: run
Target: @login
```

[image: Run @login]

which I know will do a happy path login.

I can then build on top of that with the test steps for my new functionality